# Add multiple entries to a database in one post using charfield

Tags: django, django-forms

I am building a **todo app** and for now people **can only add one "task"** at the time.

I would like to allow user to have multiple text area (5 for example) and so they can add multiple tasks in one post.

As you can see on the picture, only one input is available, I cannot add more than that without error.

[image]

I thought that maybe I could add multiple charfield in my model "todo" but that seem ugly.

**Models.py**

```
class Todo(models.Model):
author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,verbose_name="Nom de l'utilisateur")
text = models.CharField(max_length=150, verbose_name="Nom de la Todo")
content = models.TextField(verbose_name="Description supplémentaire",null=True, blank=True)
date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
complete = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name="Statut de la Todo")
urgence = models.BooleanField(default=False,verbose_name="Tâche urgente")

def __str__(self):
    return self.text

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('dashboard-home')
```

todo_form.html

```
 <form method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <fieldset class="form-group">
            <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">Ajouter une tâche à faire</legend>

            {{ form|crispy }}

        <div class="form-group">
            <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Envoyer</button>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django - Submitting form with multiple inputs for same field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47469063/django-submitting-form-with-multiple-inputs-for-same-field)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add multiple todo instances and use a formset.

There can be extremely helpful for situations just like this.

Look at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/formsets/ to see how to use the factories and create the models.

I have had success with this https://github.com/dallasmorningnews/django-dynamic-formsets for making the front end usable.

A basic model setup might be:

```
class User(models.Model):
    username = models.TextField()

class Todo(models.model):
    task = models.Textfield()
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="todos", on_delete=models.Protect)
```

And a basic formset setup might look like:

```
TodoFormSet = inlineformset_factory(User, Todo, fields=('task',))
user = User.objects.get(username='Mcflan_7')
formset = TodoFormSet(instance=user)
```

Comment: I have not done it yet but that's exaclty what I am looking for, thank you very much !

Comment: So i tried but not succeed, I added my code for better clarification. 

I don't understand the User, I am already using author so that should be good enough, then for the formset As I used CBV I don't understand how to set it up

Comment: Your author model should be fine to use instead of the User model. Look here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/modelforms/#using-an-inline-formset-in-a-view for usage in a view. This is not CBV, but you should be able to use it. The snippet under 'if request.method == "POST"' goes in your post() and the snippet under 'else' goes in your get()