# How do you implement input( or form) dependent on a select menu(drop down list)?

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, django, ajax, django-forms

I'm working on grading system and I'm currently working on the form that's deals with the user entering the students results now the form I have, has 2 drop-down list(classroom, students) that are dependent. The issue and where I'm stuck is

- When the user select the classroom the second drop-down menu will only show the students in that class, I have already figure that out..the issue is I want the input fields for how much subject the student is doing to appear so that the user can enter the grades for each subject specific to that student in the class

Eg if I select classroom 1b and selected student Mary.. if Mary is doing 5 subjects then 5 input field should appear so that I can enter the mark for the subjects

> Link with a video showing what I'm talking about [video showing an example](https://drive.google.com/file/d/11FoCZyOBVdUhTcvCqA1Ke0fEgRmMVC-G/view?usp=drivesdk)https://drive.google.com/file/d/11FoCZyOBVdUhTcvCqA1Ke0fEgRmMVC-G/view?usp=drivesdk

**Models.py**

```
    
        Class Classroom(models.Models): name = models.charfield()
    
        Class marks (models.Models): classroom = models.foreignkey(Classroom) Grade = models.Floatfield()
```

**Html form**

```
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <form id="result-form" method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <!-- Modal -->
    
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="staticBackdropLabel"> {% block modal-title%} Add Result {% endblock%}</h5>
                <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12" id="msg8" style="font-size: 2rem; color:rgb(255, 144, 47)"></div>
    
                    <div class="col-md-12 form-group p-2">
                        <label class="form-label">Class Name</label>
                        {% render_field form.room class+="form-control" %}
                    </div>
    
                    <div class="col-md-12 form-group p-2">
                        <label class="form-label">Exam Name</label>
                        {% render_field form.exam class+="form-control" %}
    
                    </div>
    
                    <div class="col-md-12 form-group p-2">
                        <label class="form-label">Student</label>
                        {% render_field form.student class+="form-control select2" %}
                    </div>
                 <div class="hidden" id="subject-fields"></div>
    
                    <div class="form-group mb-3 pt-2">
                        <button type="button" id="resBtn" class="btn btn-info" title="Add">Submit</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    
        </form>
    </div>
    
    {% block script%}
    
                
   
    
    {% endblock%
```

**script**

```
    $(document).on('click', '#submit-btn', function(event){
            var response_data = []
            var subject_name= $('.course');
            var subject_objs = $('.subject_id');
    

for(i=0;i<subject_name.length;i++){
        
        var subject_id = $(subject_objs[i]).find('input').val();
       
            var grade_input = {
                
                "Marks": subject_id,
                
            }
            response_data.push(grade_input);
        }
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "{% url 'marks' %}",
            data: response_data,
            success: function(response){
                alert("Success");
            }
        });
    });
```

This is how your view should look like.

def question_choice_view(request):
if request.method == "POST":
question_choice_data = request.POST['data']

Answer (score 1):

I am not a jQuery User. As far as i can see i would put a eventlistener on the student form via `.addEventListener('change', (event)`[See here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event). This would fire a function every time something changes on the select option. With that you could also collect the selected option values of the classroom and student name and make a request to get the subject names for the chosen student. After successful response i would insert the subject fields via JavaScript in the DOM.

**

```js
function createInput(item) {
  // This function takes a item and creates a new input
  var newLabel = ' <br><label for="$item-mark">$item:</label>'
  var newInput = '<input type="text" id="$item-mark-id" name="$item-mark"><br><br>';
  newLabel = newLabel.replaceAll("$item", item)
  newInput = newInput.replaceAll("$item", item)
  // combine into a single str
  newInput = newLabel + newInput
  var studInput = document.getElementById("student-id");
  // insert element inputs after student
  studInput.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', newInput);
}

function cleanOldInputs(item) {
  var oldELement = item + "-mark-id"
  oldELement = document.getElementById(oldELement)
  if (oldELement) {
    // remove old label and input
    oldELement.previousSibling.remove()
    oldELement.remove()
  } else {}
}

function getAPIcall() {
  // This is what your API sends
  var responsObject = ["writing", "creativity"];
  // loop throug
  responsObject.forEach(item => {
    // if you already picked a student clean old inputs from DOM
    cleanOldInputs(item)
    // send to function for input creation

    createInput(item)
  })
}


// get the Student Input
var studentSelect = document.getElementById("student-id");

studentSelect.addEventListener("click", function() {
  // Fire anything you like
  getAPIcall()
});
```

```html
<form action="/action_page.php">

  <label for="student">Choose a student:</label>

  <select name="student" id="student-id">
    <option value="harry">harry</option>
    <option value="ivy">ivy</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

Quick and dirty**

Comment: I'm guessing you would need to loop through the response from the backend so that you can get the necessary amount of fields and their correct label of the subject

Comment: Yes.  Depending on your response Object you have to iterate and you can choose different solutions.  But you could send a array   `["apple", "orange", "cherry"]`  as response and `var frutis = JSON.parse(tresponseObject)` turns it into a readable array easy to loop with `.forEach()` like `fruits.forEach(myFunctionToInsertNewInputElements);`

Comment: also, how would you get the list of marks being enter from the input fields to be saved to the backend. eg if a student has 4 subject then how would i get those 4 grades to be save.. this is the models responsible for saving the grade class Mark(models.Model):
    result = models.ForeignKey(Result,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    course = models.ForeignKey(Subject,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    grade = models.FloatField()

Comment: you could handle these input values from the injected input fields in your regular django view. After firing the submit button it would be a request. If you created  `<input type="number" name="math_grade" >` for instance in your DOM. Then you receive the request data and fetch `request.POST["math_grade"]`  for instance in your view. Afterwards apply your model, form or field validation logic. Or - because you already use Ajax calls - you could use a small API like  `django-ninja` to consume GET/ POST requests with JSON data and handle your logic there. Or did you already use Django-REST?

Comment: Nope just using regular Django and jQuery in this project

Comment: only confusion I have now is being able to add the 4 individual grade per subject since those grades are going to the same fields in the model form..I was thinking maybe I will need a loop because each fields will have a different subject_id and subject_name so how would I handle such data.. would I need to create different request for each fields or maybe give each input field the same class name then use that as a way to create a list of grades enter by the user and loop through those to save to the model form fields @black-hole_sun..

Comment: Is something like this possible:   <input type="text" id="subject_id" name="mark[]"> where the name"mark[]" is some kinda list that when the user enter the grade it somehow stores the grade in that variable then access that in the view to get all grades??

Comment: I hope i understand it right. But given to the need of a `subject` in relation to the `mark` i would introduce a subject field in your `marks` model. Either via Foreign Key or as Category. Then you could do `<input type="text" id="subject_writing_id" name="mark_writing">`.  So if your response object, after choosing a student, is a array ["writing", "creativity"]. You just loop for the items in the array and inject the `item` into a string var like `var x  = <input.... id="subject_ +  item + _id ...>`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47471241/17949867.   Something like this where you gather all the grades entered by the user then send it back to the view in a list form and then I would I guess loop through the list while assigning the grade data to the form view and the subject Id

Comment: @Speedster Check the Code Snippet i added to my answer (see top) maybe it help to understand if you run it.

Comment: From what I understand this snippet is responsible for getting the subjects then creating the input fields..I already have that implemented in my code...the issue is getting all the enter subject grades at once when I click submit and assigning them to the django model form fields responsible for grades @black_hole_sun

Comment: I have updated the question and added a script would that be able to take all the grade input once I hit submit then send them to the backend so that I can be able to loop through and get the individual grade